# Is it possible to make the application sound in Premade Groups for WoW louder?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If you create a premade group in WoW there is a small sound cue if a new person signs up for your group. Is it possible to make this sound cue for new applicants louder? Sometimes I miss it and I don't want to stare at the list of new applicants the whole time.

Not sure if there is already an addon for it or a setting just for this. I don't want to make the whole game louder.